# Which mother board is better, ATX or Micro-ATX?

Tags: motherboard

What is the difference between ATX and micro ATX motherboard or in [others](http://www.webopedia.com/DidYouKnow/Hardware_Software/2005/motherboard_form_factors.asp)?

Which is better?

If cost is not a problem which I should buy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only real difference is size and shape, and by extension the number of PCI and PCI Express slots that are available. The form factor does not govern the number of expansion slots on a board though, so be careful and read the spec sheet for any board you are considering, as a cheap manufacturer of a full ATX board might give you the exact same amount of slots as a cheaper mATX.

You should buy one that fits your need, budget and -most importantly- case.

Answer (score 1):

The typical microATX board has either 4 PCI slots or (3 PCI slots and an AGP
slot). The typical ATX board adds another two slots. An older ATX or even mATX
board may have an ISA slot or two rather than some of the PCI slots. Depending
on the model, both types of boards may have either ob-board video or an AGP slot
or both. Either type of board may have up to 6 USB ports, if you count the
usual pair connected via a cable to the front of the case. Parallel, one or two
serial, and PS/2-style keyboard and mouse connectors are almost always present
on both types.

A micro ATX board will fit in a full ATX case. An ATX board will not
fit in a microATX case. Duh! They have the same mounting screw pattern. A
microATX board looks absolutely tiny in a full ATX case, but it does the job
when you need a system with a lot of drive bays

Comment: You should brush up on current tech. Nothing's come with an AGP slot in 5 or 6 years

Comment: And quite a few boards are ditching the db-25 ports and the ps/2 as well

Comment: @MarkM: Good points, although I think the AGP slot's final demise was a little more recent. 2 or 3 years ago, one of my friends wanted to upgrade his computer on the cheap and decided to get an AGP board so he could still use his old video card. But he also wanted to be able to upgrade again without having to replace his motherboard, so he found a frankenboard which had both an AGP slot and a PCI Express slot, and could take either DDR or DDR2 RAM.  :O